# VS Code Multiple Cursors - Paste Individual Lines Repeatedly

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code with VI bindings and I am trying to do the following.

I have the following file contents:

```
abc="some value"
def="some other value"
ghi="some other other value"
jkl="some other other other value"
.
<etc. for many lines>
```

I want to make this file change to (Expected Output):

```
abc=${abc}
def=${def}
ghi=${ghi}
jkl=${jkl}
```

So far, I have first replaced `=.+` with `=${`. I get the following:

```
abc=${
def=${
ghi=${
jkl=${
```

Then I am trying to use multiple cursors in VS Code by Cntrl + Alt + I and I am trying to copy each line from the beginning to paste it so that I get the expected output. For some reason, it isn't letting me select the whole line when I do a Cntrl + Home. Could someone please help me out with this?

For reference: The VI section of my `settings.json` file is as follows:

```
// my settings
    "vim.easymotion": true,
    "vim.sneak": true,
    "vim.incsearch": true,
    "vim.useSystemClipboard": true,
    "vim.useCtrlKeys": true,
    "vim.hlsearch": true,
    "vim.handleKeys": {
    "<C-a>": false,
    "<C-f>": false,
    "<C-w>" : false,
    "<C-x>" : false,
    "<C-c>" : false,
    "<C-h>" : false,
    "<C-b>" : false,
    "<C-n>" : false
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use VI, but this is easy to do with a snippet (in your `keybindings.json`).

```
{
  "key": "alt+b",                               // whatever keybinding you wish
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "args": {
    "snippet": "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/(.*)=.*/$1=${$1}/g}"
  },
  "when": "textInputFocus && editorHasSelection"
},
```

Then select your code and <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> (or whatever keybinding you use).  You don't need multiple cursors or need to select each line separately.

[image: "VI" snippet replace]

Answer (score 1):

Why does it not work with Multi Cursor?

Using the default key bindings.

- position cursor before `a`
- use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>DownArrow</kbd> as often as you like
- use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>RightArrow</kbd> select all before the `=`
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
- <kbd>RightArrow</kbd> 2 times
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> select all after the `=`
- <kbd>$</kbd><kbd>{</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>
- <kbd>Esc</kbd>

Or start selecting `="` followed by

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> <kbd>LeftArrow</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>RightArrow</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> <kbd>$</kbd><kbd>{</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Home</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd>